# How to access original props inside CreateContainer?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I have amazingly simple and terrible problem.

Let's say, I have a React component (called `List`) wrapped by `createContainer`:

```
class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
export default createContainer({
  ...
}, List);
```

`List` has one prop from parent: `activeListId`.

I use `createContainer` to subscribe for subscription, but i need to pass a parameter inside that subscription. The parameter is `activeListId` value.

```
export default createContainer({
  Meteor.subscribe('ListItems', this.props.activeListId);
  return {
    ...
  }
}, List);
```

So I need to have an access to props of the original component inside the `createContainer` code. It is so strange but I can not do this! `this` context inside `createContainer` is different from `this` inside `List`.

Who knows how to achieve that?

Comment: Or may be there is a way to pass prop to createContainer itself ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As its first argument, `createContainer` should receive a function that takes `props` as an argument. So you need to do this:

```
export default createContainer(props => {
  Meteor.subscribe('ListItems', props.activeListId);
  return {
    ...
  }
}, List);
```

Comment: If anybody looks for mor info then there is an article in the official guide: https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer